# htaccess 301 to redirect .com to .co.uk, http to https and non-www to www subdomain

Tags: htaccess, https, http

I have `example.co.uk` and `example.com` domain names. 
The main website is `example.co.uk`. 
I have an SSL certificate on the domain `example.co.uk`.

I want the `.htaccess` file to 301 redirect everything seen in a browser to `https:` without affecting SEO.

This means entries of:

- `example.co.uk`
- `example.com`
- `www.example.com`
- `www.example.co.uk`
- `http://example.co.uk`
- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.co.uk`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://example.co.uk`
- `https://example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`

would all forward to `https://www.example.co.uk`.

This is a single-page site, so "catch-all" type solution will work. 
Ideally, I'd like this to work for a multipage site. So I could use the `.htaccess` code again in different projects.

I came up with the following, but it converts `.com` entries to `https://example.com` or `https://www.example.com` then stops:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R]
```

Comment: You need a valid SSL cert on both domains to redirect from `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com` to `example.co.uk` regardless if it's just a redirect, this is because your actually visiting a website to obtain the redirect and not having one will stop the user with a warning. You can use Cloudflare which will provide a free SSL cert and redirect all to the `example.co.uk` website using page rules.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an SSL certificate on the domain `example.co.uk`.

Presumably this also covers the `www` subdomain? (It would need to.)

> ```
> https://example.com
> https://www.example.com
> ```

As mentioned by Simon in comments, in order to redirect `https://example.com` you will need an SSL cert that covers the `example.com` domain. Otherwise, the browser will stop at the invalid certificate warning. (The SSL handshake occurs *before* your server is able to process the request.)

> I came up with the following, but it converts `.com` entries to `https://example.com` or `https://www.example.com` then stops:

Presumably because you are getting an invalid certificate warning?

Since you have multiple domains, it is perhaps easier to construct a rule that redirects anything that is *not* the canonical host, rather than trying to positively match everything that it could be. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.co.uk
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This combines both HTTPS and www canonicalisation into a single rule.

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the expression, so it is successful when it does not match the given string/regex. In this case, it is successful when the *host* is not the string `www.example.co.uk`. The `=` prefix is the *exact match* (lexicographical comparison) operator, so the remaining *CondPattern* is seen as an ordinary string, not a regex.

Do you need the `NE` (`noescape`) flag? You omitted it on the first rule, so you'd naturally lose any special characters that passed through this directive anyway.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.uk$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R]
> ```

*Aside:* Since you are using `HTTP_HOST` in the *substitution* in the first `RewriteRule`, if you switched the order of these rules then you'd avoid an unnecessary second redirect when accessing `http://example.co.uk` etc. Since it is only after the second rule that you know the host is canonicalised.